# React Router - useNavigate.navigate not working when I manually enter the path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

The title summarize it. The code below works when trying to navigate from the UI, but when I manually enter the path, it doesn't redirect to the Login page.
What I'm not seeing?

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const DetailView = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  let token = localStorage.getItem('token');

  return (
    <>
      {!token && navigate("/", { replace: true })}
      <h2>DetailView</h2>
    </>
  );
};

export default DetailView;
```

Comment: Are there any errors? Also, why are you redirecting as an unintentional side-effect in the render? You should really be using a `useEffect` hook for the side-effect.

Comment: How is this `DetailView` component rendered? Can you include all relevant code, i.e. the routing/navigation code, as a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live that could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

you need to perform this operation in useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    !token && navigate("/", { replace: true });
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Why my code works in the other component if it's a copy and paste?

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in a useEffect, and include the token as a dependency.

```js
useEffect(() => {
!token && navigate("/", { replace: true });
}, [token]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Why my code works in the other component if it's a copy and paste?

Comment: I'm not sure about the other component without inspecting the other component.

Answer (score 0):

following the answers by Aman Sadhwani and Moath:
what happen is :

in your code (not sure about this one) the navigation will happen only using the ui, because that what registers it, manually adding the url will not trigger the token to navigate

but when using built in `useEffect` you tell react to constantly update,
it has `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount` blended in

```
useEffect(() => {
    !token && navigate("/", { replace: true });
}, [token]);
```

that will trigger the navigation each time the token changes, and always use [] in the end to avoid being in an infinite loop either empty or with passed data

read more [react-hooks-effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)